# Angular google maps places autocomplete not showing all places

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I want to integrate google maps placeholder so that end user can search for his/her places but in vanilla javascript I've integrated this and works as expected and now I'm trying to convert it into Angular 4 project everything works fine except for the fact that my google maps placeholder is just showing me only selected places. You can consider this [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/LdKdSj/) because I'm also using this code. Further I'm using Angular Google Map module. Please suggest alternative to this API or any work around? I've embedded my code below:

TS FILE

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, NgZone, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";
import {MapsAPILoader} from "@agm/core";
declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  constructor(
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {}
  title = 'app';
  // google maps zoom level
  zoom: number = 8;
  // initial center position for the map
  lat: number = 51.673858;
  lng: number = 7.815982;
  markers: marker[] = [
    {
      lat: 51.673858,
      lng: 7.815982,
      label: 'A',
      draggable: true
    },
    {
      lat: 51.373858,
      lng: 7.215982,
      label: 'B',
      draggable: false
    },
    {
      lat: 51.723858,
      lng: 7.895982,
      label: 'C',
      draggable: true
    }
  ];

  public latitude: number;
  public longitude: number;
  public searchControl: FormControl;
  @ViewChild('search')
  public searchElementRef: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.zoom = 4;
    this.latitude = 39.8282;
    this.longitude = -98.5795;

    //create search FormControl
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();

    //set current position
    this.setCurrentPosition();

    //load Places Autocomplete
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
        types: ["address"]
      });
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          //get the place result
          let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

          //verify result
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }

          //set latitude, longitude and zoom
          this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
          this.zoom = 12;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  private setCurrentPosition() {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        this.zoom = 12;
      });
    }
  }

  clickedMarker(label: string, index: number) {
    console.log(`clicked the marker: ${label || index}`);
  }

  mapClicked($event: any) {
    // console.log($event);
    this.markers.push({
      lat: $event.coords.lat,
      lng: $event.coords.lng,
      label: 'A',
      draggable: true
    });
  }


  markerDragEnd(m: marker, $event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('dragEnd', m, $event);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
        types: ["address"]
      });
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          //get the place result
          let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

          //verify result
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }

          //set latitude, longitude and zoom
          this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
          this.zoom = 12;
        });
      });
    });
  }



}

interface marker {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  label?: string;
  draggable: boolean;
}
```

HTML File

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Angular 2 + Google Maps Places Autocomplete</h1>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input placeholder="search for location" autocorrect="off"
           autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control" #search >
  </div>
  <agm-map
    (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)"
    [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"
    [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
    <agm-marker
    *ngFor="let marker of markers"
    [latitude]="marker.lat"
    [longitude]="marker.lng"
    ></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
</div>
```

Comment: `just showing me only selected places` What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I need that user is free to search all places as it happens in maps API provided by google I achieved this thing (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) in vanilla javascript but uncertain how to achieve it in Angular 4

Answer (score 4):

Because in types parameter you have passed "address".So only addresses will be searched.

For more info go to following link:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types

Just remove types and you will get all places in search.

let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement);

Answer (score 3):

**I removed "address" from nativeElement and it worked for me.**
i.e Replace with this:

let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElement.nativeElement,{});